# Exercise 2.3 Lee's Riemmanian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

**Statement:** Suppose $M\subseteq \tilde{M}$ is an embedded submanifold.

a)If $f$ is any smooth function on $M$, show that $f$ can be extended to a smooth function on $\tilde{M}$ whose restriction to $M$ is $f$.

**Question:** So I'm wondering if there is some mistake in the statement, since there seems to be a simple counterexample, namely $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. If it is a simple oversight, how should the question be reworded? I have been able to prove it assuming $f$ is a smooth function on some closed sub manifold, but I am unsure if that was the intended question.

Comment: I think I remember looking at the errata and seeing that M must be closed.

Comment: It's a typo as @Gary mentioned.   Is that an older version of Lee's book?

Comment: It might be. I got it used.

Comment: An embedded submanifold is sometimes taken to be closed. Given that (or assuming the omission is a mistake), the result follows almost immediately from taking a tubular neighborhood around $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close out this question: @Gary is correct -- this exercise is incorrectly stated in my book. A corrected version is in my [list of errata](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Riemannian/errata.pdf).

Note that there are two ways to modify the statement so as to obtain a correct result: One is to ask only that $f$ be extended to some open set containing $M$; and the other is to assume that $M$ is a closed embedded submanifold.